# Trying to add "Title:" with span to woocommerce product name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, title

I am trying to add a span that I can format in CSS to match the rest of my product page.

At the moment, I have a plugin called additional attributes that displays custom product details below the image which look great, but the title of the product seems impossible to add a label to.

Here's what I mean;
https://www.jeremynative.com/shop/ayeuonganit-wampum-ayim%EA%9D%8Fup-wampum-made/

Just like the Date, Medium, Dimensions - I'm trying to figure how to simply add

Title: Ayeuonganit.....

I know how to do it using :before, but I want to do it in a function and wrap it in a span that I can format to look like the other labels and attributes.

Comment: Seems like you have done this already... I checked the example page you have linked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it was resolved;

```
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title',5);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_my_single_title',5);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_my_single_title' ) ) {
   function woocommerce_my_single_title() {
?>
            <span>Title: </span><h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php
    }
}
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/7a68ln/how_to_add_label_to_woocommerce_title/